# Could someone explain this php mysql script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, arrays

Could someone explain what exactly happens when this script executes. It works like a charm but I don't feel satisfied not knowing what exactly it does.

Basically I have a sql table [images]  with the following fields

- Filename
- Caregory
- URL

what I wanted to do is fetch all the values of [URL] and place it in an array

to achieve this I used to following script I found here on stackoverflow

```
$images = mysql_query("Select URL from images where Category = 'Management' ");
$imagerow = Array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images) )
{
$imagerow[] = $row['URL'];
}

echo $imagerow[0] ;
```

The script works like a charm, but being new to php and mysql I find it tough to understand what exactly happens. I'll like it if someone explained in simple words as to what happens.

Comment: The query result is stored in `$images` over which the iteration is done. The `'URL'` column is fetched from individual record(s) and stored into a new placeholder `$imagerow` which is then used as desired.

Comment: I could not understand why the `while` loop was being used. @ranty's answer kinda solved it though. I apologize for asking an unnecessary question, just that I don't believe in copy pasting code.

Comment: @TDsouza: that's fine. Just make sure you explain clearly what you don't understand next time please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not really belong here, but I'll answer it for the sake of closing the question without bothering moderators.

```
// mysql query is executed
$images = mysql_query("Select URL from images where Category = 'Management' ");

// empty array initialized
$imagerow = Array();

// while there are results of the executed mysql query
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($images) )
{
    // create a new element in $imagerow array and put url of the image there
    $imagerow[] = $row['URL'];
}

// output first element of the array we have just filled
echo $imagerow[0] ;
```

Comment: Thank You that made things clear. It was the `while` that confused me.